# Remove Chapter, chapter number and chapter dot from header but not from TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, wrapfigure

I would like to remove the word "Chapter", the chapter number AND the period that appears directly after this number from my header in this project. My current code does not remove this dot, and removes the chapter numbers from all of my figures, which I do NOT want. I want my figures to be labeled in the Figure 1.1 style still. Any help would be great!

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany, numbers=noenddot]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{What is the Mercenarium Arcade?}

Mercenarium is Anthromancer’s original game of strategy and chance, but a collection of variants and other new games can be played with the same components. This collection is referred to as the Mercenarium Arcade:

\section{Mercenarium \textcolor{red}{(p.xx)}}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Players: 2--4
\item Time: 30 minutes
\item Genre: Abstract Strategy/Chance
\end{itemize}

Mercenarium is an abstract strategy game with a neoclassical aesthetic. Players take turns placing and moving cards around the board to try and overcome the dot values on the edges of their opponent’s cards. Players compete to be the first to (5) captures, or to eliminate their opponents by blocking their houses. Face cards on the board (J, Q, K, or A) are called Mercenaries and can be ‘bought’ by an opponent with an unspent capture to subvert strategies, while hymn cards offer unique powers that alter the flow of the game in surprising and dramatic ways. Mercenarium rewards strategic thinking and the luck of the draw in equal measure.\\

\textbf{Variants: High, Classic, Mad \textcolor{red}{(p.xx)}}\\

\section{Zealot \textcolor{red}{(p.xx)}} 

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Players: 2 or more
\item Time: 20 minutes or more
\item Genre: Speed/Pattern recognition
\end{itemize}

Zealot is a twist on Rat Screw, a classic card-capturing and pattern recognition game. The deck is divided evenly between all players, who then take turns drawing cards from their own piles and placing them face-up on a central pile. When courts or hymns appear, the next player in rotation has between 1 and 5 chances to beat the previous card depending upon its value. If they succeed, play continues to the next player; if they fail, the previous player takes the pile. When certain patterns appear in the pile, the first player to ‘slap’ the pile with their hand takes the pile. The objective is to take possession of all cards in the deck. Wear rings for additional pain.\\

\section{Solitarium \textcolor{red}{(p.xx)}}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item Players: 1
\item Time: 20 minutes
\item Genre: Solitaire
\end{itemize}

Solitarium is an original solitaire. The player places a 5x5 tableau of cards face-up and attempts to find dot matches between adjacent cards to remove those cards from play. When a Hymn is matched (which matches with its colored element instead of dots), the player keeps it, and may discard it later in order to rotate a card in the tableau or sweep cards into empty spaces. The objective is to clear the deck using as few hymns as possible. The number of hymns held at the end of the game determines the player’s score.

\clearpage

\section{Rulebook: Mercenarium}

For 2-4 players. Average game time: 30 minutes.\\

\subsection*{Components:}

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\item[(1)] (71)-card Anthromancer Deck
\item[(1)] (4) quick reference cards (one for each player)
\item[(2)] 6-sided dice (the blue Fool die and the purple Fox die)
\item[(1)] 12-sided Zodiac die
\item[(1)] Anthromancer board
\end{itemize}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim=7.5mm 5mm 7.5mm 7.5mm, width=0.48\textwidth, clip]{1-1.png}
\caption{\scriptsize{The Board: Houses and player seating}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection*{Set Up:}

\textbf{House Placement:} Open your game board and place it face up on a sturdy, flat surface. On the board there are colored circles in the center space along each board edge that are either Red, Orange, Yellow, or Green, and have a small black emblem in their center. These spaces are called \textbf{houses} and each player will be in control of one during the game. Have each player sit at the house that they will control. In 2-player games, players should sit directly across from each other.\\

\textbf{NOTE:} The center space has no special gameplay function in Mercenarium.\\

\pagebreak

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim=1cm 0cm 1cm 0cm, width=0.5\textwidth, clip]{1-2.png}
\caption{\scriptsize{Hymn card anatomy}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\textbf{Dealing:} Remove the 15 Hymn cards from the Anthromancer deck and place them in a separate face-down pile. Hymn cards have roman numerals and titles along their bottom edge and blue emblems and borders on their backs. This separate pile will be referred to as the \textbf{hymnal}, while the remaining 56 cards will be referred to as the \textbf{deck}.\\  

Once the hymns have been separated, shuffle the deck and deal five (5) cards to each player. Then, shuffle the hymnal, and deal one (1) hymn to each player. Combined, these six (6) cards are your starting \textbf{hand}. You should never hold more than one (1) hymn or more than five (5) non-hymn cards in your hand, except during Singularity (see Ending the Game). Set the deck and the hymnal at the outside corners of the board where all players can reach them.\\

New players should receive a copy of the Anthromancer Quick Reference card turned to the side labeled ‘Mercenarium Quick Reference’. This card contains useful information and will help keep the game running smoothly.\\

\textbf{Turn Order:} Take turns rolling 6-sided dice to decide who goes first. The player who rolls the highest number goes first. If there is a tie, tied players re-roll the dice until the tie is broken. Turns proceed in clockwise order.\\

\textbf{NOTE:} The 6-sided Fool and Fox dice have unique symbols in the place of 6s. For establishing turn order these symbols count as 6s.\\

\end{document}
```

Images attached to point out specific issues.

[image: Figure mislabeled]
[image: Chapter number removed but dot remains]

Comment: How should your actual chapter and section headings look like? Currently, they are missing its number as well. Or do you actually want unnumbered chapters, sections,...? Please clarify.

Comment: I want unnumbered chapters and sections. I want my figures to have chapter labels though

Comment: How should a reader find a figure numbered "figure 3.4" if there is no actual "chapter 3" there? Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just number the figures continuously throughout the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively what you need to do is not number chapters:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

not number figures within chapters:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
```

but number them within a parallel counter

```
\newcounter{Chapter}
\counterwithin{figure}{Chapter}
```

that gets incremented with each chapter:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\refstepcounter{Chapter}}{}{\OopsSomethingWentWrong}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want two impossible things. No chapter numbers but figure numbers to be preceded by chapter numbers. Please think again.

To get figure numbers just by themselves, without preceding chapter numbers and continuously throughout the document in your preamble add:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I would like. I realize that there may not be an easy fix for this. Any suggestions for removing the dot in the header?

Comment: @Pyro1368 No, please rethink your whole idea. --- GOM